# Would there be any benefit to having a "gairaigo" tag in addition to the "loanwords" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Are the terms "gairaigo" and "loanword" synonymous within the scope of this website?

I've seen people use the term "gairaigo" within questions, answers, or comments; and I considered adding it as a tag but when I noticed we already had a "loanwords" tag I used that instead.

But I'm wondering if there's any possible overlap with subtle distinctions in which case there could be merit in having both. If not, when somebody first uses a "gairaigo" tag we can just make it a tag synonym for "loanwords".

What think ye?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, we should add gairaigo as synonyms of loanwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I concur, both tags should be synonyms. But a separate tag for wasei-eigo can be useful. :)

Comment: can you have a hierarchy in the tags?  Like wasei-eigo be a child tag of loanwords?

Comment: @Mark: Currently there is no feature like that in the Stack Exchange system.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with YOU; we should not have [gairaigo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gairaigo) as a separate tag from [loanwords](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loanwords).  I think that they are just the same notion in Japanese and English, but even if there are some corner cases where one is appropriate and the other is not, their meanings have a very large overlap and it is more useful to have one tag rather than distinguishing the two tags.